# Bounty: what did I miss?

Tags: discussion, support, bounty

I have written an [answer to a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49968316/groupwise-sorting-in-pandas/49968504#49968504) that had a bounty of 150 points. The bounty period has ended, as has the grace period. The OP has not logged in since Apr 28 and has not accepted any of the answers. My answer received six upvotes.

My understanding is that half of the bounty should have been awarded to me automatically, yet nothing along these lines has happened. This makes me wonder what I misunderstood about how the automatic award mechanism works. Could someone point out what went awry?

Comment: @DiskJunky What is it with you junkies and misinformation? You mean 6-8 weeks.

Comment: @coldspeed  habit ;)